# Java - Как проверить причину вылета программы

Tags: java, android

Как проверить ошибку в приложении на адроиде?
К примеру, если программа вылетает на определенном моменте, как проследить?
Слышал, что остаются логи программы, но не знаю где и что..

Answer (score 2):

Используйте окошко с LogCat, там будут все логи с устройства, надо будет задать в фильтре ваше имя пакета и смотреть логи.

Answer (score 0):

Android monitor вкладка в нижней части android studio. Там красным цветом обычно ошибки(exception)

Comment: Не используя эмулятор и соединение со средой разработки, есть логи, которые остаются после ошибки программы в телефоне.

Comment: @J.Defenses таких логов "из коробки" не существует. Для того чтобы смотреть логи на недосягаемых для вас устройствах используйте [библиотеки](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android%20crash%20reporting&oq=android%20crash%20reporting)

Comment: дополню комментарий @zTrap  - можно так же использовать, помимо файрбеса, BugTags, BugSee, Crashlytics

Comment: @abbath0767, хорошее дополнение, но я не уточнял по поводу библиотеки, `Firebase` просто стоит первый в запросе в google, который я указал в виду ссылки